# rsync using function args

Tags: bash, shell, rsync

I'm trying to create a BASH function that I can use to pass arguments into rsync to specify the files and/or directories to download. Assume the server has the following files I'd like to download (the spaces and underscores are intentional...the important part is that the files have spaces in them):

```
dir1/file 1 with really long name.txt
dir1/file 2_with_shorter_name.txt
```

Currently, I have the following:

```
CMD="ssh -i~/.ssh/some_key"
LOGIN="user@server.com"

dl()
{
    rsync -Pzr --compress-level=9 -e "$CMD" "$LOGIN":"$@" ./
}
```

I'm trying to call this function like so to download these two files:

```
dl "dir1/file\ *"
```

(I'd really like to be able to pass the asterisk in to my `dl` function so that it can be passed through rsync to the server)

But rsync exits with the following error:

```
receiving incremental file list
rsync: link_stat "/home/user/dir1/file\ *" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors (code 23) at main.c(1655) [Receiver=3.1.1]
rsync: [Receiver] write error: Broken pipe (32)
```

I suspect something's wrong with my quoting here...anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Note that if I just call rsync by itself, not in a function, it works as expected:

```
rsync -Pzr --compress-level=9 -e "ssh -i~/.ssh/some_key" "user@server.com":"dir1/file\ *" ./
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The output of `ssh -v` has the following line:

```
rsync --server --sender -vrze.iLsfx --compress-level=9 . dir1/file\\ *
```

To my surprise, the command is actually magically working now, and the files are downloading. Maybe I had a typo earlier in the path I was passing in? Unfortunately, the `.bash_history` entry was deleted by now, so I have no way to tell. Anyways, does that rsync command look correct?

Comment: Read the last part of my post. rsync works as expected if it's not placed in a function...indicating that yes, wildcards are expanded; yes, I'm able to use rsync manually to the server I'm trying to reach; and yes, `ssh -i` is correct

Comment: Also, note that I'm using rsync 3.1.1, and I don't have a `--preserve-args` option

Comment: That's a typo: the `-s` option is also `--protect-args`, and should be in 3.1.1

Comment: Doh; I had an `unset CMD LOGIN` after the function definition, which was not shown in the OP. I removed that line, and updated to show the new error message...maybe this makes more sense now.

Comment: can you `echo "$LOGIN"` before and after your `dl()` function to see if it's passing with currect USER, or can you please change `LOGIN` variable to something else like `myLOGIN`

Comment: Change both ssh parts to include `-v` so you get debug from ssh: *debug1: Sending command: rsync --server --sender...* and compare both.  Add option `-v --debug=CMD2` to the rsync parts to see what args it passes to ssh: *cmd[0]=ssh cmd[1]=-i~/.ssh/id_rsa ...* and compare both.

Comment: As described this seems to work as expected for me here. If you add `-vvv` to the `rsync` command does it shed any light on the issue?

Comment: @Fox no, wildcards are always expanded. Without `-s`, a source argument of `abc/def ghi/jkl` is treated as two files (`abc/def` and `ghi/jkl`). With the `-s` option the space is considered to be part of the directory name `def ghi` and the result is a single file.

Comment: @AFSHIN my apologies--`LOGIN` isn't the actual variable name I'm using, I just changed it away from the proprietary name. I'll change the variable name in the example to avoid the confusion.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do in this situation now...it turns out that @roaima was right, and it's actually working as expected for me now too. Maybe I just simply had a typo in the path I was typing in before? At any rate, I'm not sure how I should close the question, because it's 'solved' at this point...someone else may definitely find this to be useful, so it probably shouldn't be deleted, but does anyone know how I should close it?

Comment: There is a link at the bottom of the page as "Answer your own question", please post the solution worked as an answer, and mark it as accepted.

Comment: You might want to ```echo "$LOGIN":"$@"``` — I believe that it’s not doing what you think it is.